# Cordova 3.4.0 custom plugins not found

Tags: cordova, cordova-3, cordova-plugins

I have encountered an issue that my create plugins can't be loaded.

Module 'plugin ID' not found. But I installed it properly. I saw that it has an outstanding error but based on this https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5647 it should be fixed under 3.4.0.rc-1 or higher versions. Also it states that they removed the Staging folder but I still have it when I create a project. Can somebody explain what does the Staging folder's purpose?

Thank you

Comment: refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23685186/purpose-of-staging-folder-in-phonegap-3-4-only-changes-to-index-html-in-this-fo