# Cordova + Xcode 7.3 (html + Javascript) not changed or updated when build and emulate

Tags: xcode, cordova

Im a beginner hybrid mobile apps.

Im able to create my hellocordova apps. but when i edit my html file and then build it. it remains same. The apps does not changed at all. i already erase and leave blank my index.html but after i build it still show default cordova index.html.

Im already google it and try to clean + build.

Almost every ways i already try on stackoverflow but never worked. i decide to ask a question because all the solution i try on stack never worked.

How do i solve this problem

Comment: Which version of Cordova are you using, what does `cordova -version` output?

Comment: as you have added xcode tag, from where you are writing your html ?, if you are chaging from the platform/xcode it will not work after you build

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are directly changing html from the Xcode, then you should change the code/html of the **staging** folder, not main folder

In the staging folder you will get same structure which you have in the main folder, but it will reflected directly in the xcode (iOS) build

[image: Stagging folder]

**Note:** The changes you made in the xcode will be replace when you build again from the cordova build/run, so please copy your changes in the main folder before doing firing cordova commands

You can get more information from this answer: [Purpose of Staging folder in PhoneGap 3.4? Only changes to index.html in this folder get recognized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23685186/purpose-of-staging-folder-in-phonegap-3-4-only-changes-to-index-html-in-this-fo)